# Variable int que acepte cualquier valor

Tags: c#

intento que una variable int procese cualquier valor que se le asigne. Me explico:

Tengo las variables

```
string input ="cadena de texto 1 de entre muchos";

string output ="Tu texto es el número 1 de entre todos";
```

¿Hay alguna forma de decirle a VS esto?:

```
string input ="cadena de texto" + int.ToString() +"de entre muchos" ;

string output ="Tu texto es el número" + int.ToString() + "de entre todos";
```

Para situarnos, quiero que busque en todo un *richtextbox* todas las frases que sean **input** y las convierta a **output** (teniendo en cuenta que quizás haya 4 frases con distinto número). Esto lo hago con el método **regex.replace** para que reemplace input por output, pero el número de ingreso cada vez es diferente, por lo que no sé qué número ni cuántos habrá.

He tratado de usar esto para que el número sea cada vez distinto:

```
numeracion = numeracion + Convert.ToDouble(1);
Convert.ToString(numeracion);
```

Pero esto no me funciona porque todo el código está dentro del mismo evento, y esto suma a la variable cada vez que se ejecuta el evento.

Comment: A ver, lo que entendi es que quieres saber ¿como buscar en un richtextbox la frace de input? o ¿Anidar un Dato Int a un String? o ¿como saber si una frace tiene un numero ? podrias ser mas claro en la pregunta?

Comment: Básicamente, cómo reemplazar una misma cadena de texto con un número que cada vez es distinto. Gracias por ayudar.

Comment: ¿Ese `string` sólo va a tener un número? Es decir, ¿esta frase *"Esto 32 tiene 2 números"* es válida?

Comment: Tiene más números pero solo quiero que se adapte el que se especifique (porque el resto son los mismos en input y output). 
Usando tu ejemplo, el richtextbox puede tener 3 frases como la tuya:

"Esto 32 tiene 2 números"
"Esto 56 tiene 2 números"
"Esto 38 tiene 2 números"

Por lo que ves, quiero que el método replace tenga en cuenta los números 32, 56 y 38 y me los mantenga en el output. (repito que estos números pueden ser cualquiera, ahí está el problema...)

Comment: Lo lei muchas veces y no termino de entender el problema, porque veo que en tu entrada tienes un texto, luego ese texto cambia, pero haces incapie que quieres trabajar sobre el numero y la frase. Donde comienza y termina tu frase? Podrias colocar el texto completo y decir que quieres extraer y hacer con la extracción?

Answer (score 0):

Serial algo asi amigo.

```
String input = " Est es la frace que 32 veces se repite y contien 2 numeros que se repite 290 veces o hasta 999999";
string[] numbers = Regex.Split(input, @"\D+");
            foreach (string value in numbers)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                {
                    int i = int.Parse(value);
                    Console.WriteLine("Number: {0}", i);
                }
            }
```

Fuente:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734116/find-and-extract-a-number-from-a-string